# Drupal 7 notifications and subscriptions module

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Which is the best module for notifications and subscriptions for D7 which is actively maintained and has a stable release ? .. Is there any which exist ?
What are the possible alternatives that one can use to implement the subscription and notifications via email to a group of subscribed users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more specifics about your use case, it's not clear which one is "best." [Notifications](http://dgo.to/notifications) & [Subscriptions](http://dgo.to/subscriptions) modules differ in important respects, though the former is actually a fork of the latter.   Subscriptions, being the older one, is both more straight-forward as to what it does, and also a bit clunkier on the code side (although it did get a major rewrite by chx for the 2.x branch.) Notifications was a rewrite of Subscriptions intended to make it much more extendable but this is not to say Subscriptions isn't itself extensible; they're both modular frameworks.

If all you need is a way for users to subscribe to nodes you may find Subscriptions does everything you need. If however you need to support more integration points, Notifications may be the better match. I think it has a lot more modules in Contrib that already extend it, and is being used on about 3x as many sites as Subscriptions (not sure what the breakdown is for just D7 sites.)

Comment: As of august 2013,there is still no recommended (stable) release of notifications for D7 - who would dare taking on modules, that are in development for a Drupal version (soon)  to be replaced?

Answer (score 3):

How about the seemingly popular module [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions/)? It's been around since 2003 and is actively maintened with stable releases for Drupal 6 and 7. From their site:

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to
>   nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or
>   additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have
>   an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions.
>   Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions.
>   Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user
>   if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can turn this on by
>   default.

*Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with this module or its developers.*

Answer (score 3):

I nearly the same question [over here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/251038). There I got this helpful answer from the maintainer of the [Rules module](http://drupalmodules.com/module/rules).

> "My guess is you haven't tried Rules too much. All skepticism aside,
>   Rules is the right choice. Those two modules have legacy code from 4.6
>   and even earlier, but the only function that's needed is
>   drupal_mail(). Everything else is just going to make your work either
>   easier or harder."

Answer (score 1):

I am using [the Flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag) which has a pretty good Rules integration and it works great for simple "event > condition > action (send email)" notifications.

Comment: ..the module [Flag Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_notify) uses flags for the front-end to provide a simple but powerful notification system of content/comments and/or organic groups (disclaimer: I am the author :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be using [message module](https://drupal.org/project/message) and [message notify](https://drupal.org/project/message_notify) (both with stable releases with more than 10K installation).

From the module description page:

> This module provides a method for sending a message via a notifier plugin. Message Notify comes with plugins for email and SMS and may be extended to other transport mechanisms as required.
>
> Message Notify is part of the message stack, a suite of modules that provide a framework for messaging and notifications.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the subscriptions module and it works fine.

I have allowed authentified users to subscribe for certain content types of certains taxonomies.

The emails can be sent at a certain periodicity and the email templates can be modified using mail_edit.

I used an option that send a digest email once a week combining a teaser of every new content type since the last digest

Answer (score 0):

The [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) module is another alternative for subscriptions. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.
>
> ... provides users the ability to:
>
> - Subscribe to a specific content type through the node page.
> - Subscribe to the related taxonomy terms associated with the node on the node page.
> - Subscribe to a specific taxonomy term from the term page.
> - Unsubscribe from any previous subscription.
> - Add a separate ctools content type - "subscription", which could be integrated with any panel page.
> - Add a "subscription" block to the any region.

Refer to its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2170825) for more details about it, or this [video tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jL41iZfxmpM) (without sound ...) that takes you through various admin screens.

Apart from that, to understand what this module is about, the [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/total_subscription/tree/README.txt) might be helpful also